# How to highlight a row if three conditions are met?

Tags: excel, vba, highlight, conditional-statements

If the following conditions are met:

For any given row between row 10 and row 100 inclusively:

- The cell in column A is not empty
- The cell in column B is not empty
- The cell in column O is empty

I would like to highlight a specific cell (let's say A1).

Example:

I populate A10 and E10 while leaving O10 empty, then cell A1 gets highlighted. If I then populate cell O10, the highlight in cell A1 disappears.

I can proceed to the next row. Any row at any time should generate these actions.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try something yourself or is this a task you just give to the community to solve?

Comment: I attempted conditional formatting. Realized it wasn't going to work. Need VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA: just use conditional formatting on cell A10 with the following formula:

`=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($A10)),NOT(ISBLANK($B10)),ISBLANK($O10))`

Comment: Nope. A1 is the cell to be highlighted, if the three conditions are met on either of the 100 lines (A10:O110)

Answer (score 1):

This will do the highlights based on the conditions you specified. When you run it, it'll stop at the first row you need to input something in column O. If you want it to keep running until row 101 and highlight all the rows, then remove then Exit Do command that's between the 2 End If statements.

```
Sub Highlight()

    Dim TheRow As Integer

    TheRow = 9

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'This hides the visual process and speeds up
                                        'the execution

    Do

        TheRow = TheRow + 1

        If TheRow = 101 Then Exit Do

        Cells(TheRow, 1).Select
        Selection.Interior.Pattern = 0

        Cells(TheRow, 2).Select
        Selection.Interior.Pattern = 0

        If Not Cells(TheRow, 1).Value = "" And Not Cells(TheRow, 2).Value = "" And Cells(TheRow, 15).Value = "" Then

            If Cells(TheRow, 1).Value = "" Then
                Cells(TheRow, 1).Select
                Selection.Interior.Color = 656
            End If

             If Cells(TheRow, 2).Value = "" Then
                Cells(TheRow, 2).Select
                Selection.Interior.Color = 656
            End If

            Exit Do  'this is the line to remove if you want to highlight all cells

        End If

    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

And then, create an event handler that triggers when a cell in column 15 changes. Put the following code in the module of the actual worksheet (in the VBA project explorer, double click on the sheet you want have this functionality for; don't put this in a different module!)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 15 Then
        If Target.Row > 9 And Target.Row < 101 Then Call Highlight
End Sub
```

Let me know if this solution works and remember to click "accept solution" and to vote for it!

Happy coding.

Comment: Seems to work, but only if I run the macro. I would need this to continuously "sniff" for blank cells andvautomatically unhighlight when column 15 is populated.

Comment: Just edited the solution: the event handler will do what you need.

Comment: Ok, still have issues with this. I need to be more clear. For each given row (11 to 110), I need to populate columns A, B, C and any one of the following from E to N. Once these four cells are populated, the cell to be highlighted is in row 10(always) but matches the column (from E to N). Finally, when column O is populated for the given row, the highlighted cell in row 10 returns to normal. Example, I populate: A22, B22, C22 and J22. In this case, J10 gets highlighted...because I chose column J.  After, J10 returns to normal when populating O22. The same should apply to all rows 11-110.

Comment: What does this mean: Once these four cells are populated, the cell to be highlighted is in row 10(always) but matches the column (from E to N)???? What happens if we're on row 56? What gets highlighted?

Comment: If we're on row 56 and got A56, B56, C56 ... And any other between E56 to N56, then the corresponding E10 to N10 gets highlighted until O56 is populated.

Comment: What does "the corresponding" mean? How do they correspond? There's one cell E10 but many rows.

Comment: I'll look at it later tonight; this looks awfully convoluted IMO

Answer (score 1):

OK - I misunderstood what you wanted. Here is a VBA UDF to do the checking.
Enter `=Checker($A$10:$B$100,$O$10:$O$100)` in cell A1, then use conditional formatting on cell A1 that is triggered when it becomes True.

```
Public Function Checker(theRangeAB As Range, theRangeO As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim varAB As Variant
    Dim varO As Variant
    Dim j As Long

    varAB = theRangeAB.Value2
    varO = theRangeO.Value2

    Checker = False
    For j = 1 To UBound(varAB)
        If Not IsEmpty(varAB(j, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(varAB(j, 2)) Then
            If IsEmpty(varO(j, 1)) Then
                Checker = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next j

End Function
```

Comment: I would write this as: `If Not IsEmpty(varAB(j, 1)) Then: If Not IsEmpty(varAB(j, 2)) Then: If IsEmpty(varO(j, 1)) Then` because there's no point in checking column B if column A is empty.